# ProgressBars are not visible after updating compileSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, gradle, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I recently updated the APIs and set my Gradle to these settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp.myappmobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 32
        versionName "4.6.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this update, none of the progressbars are visible when i run the app on my device (Galaxy S4: Android 5.0.1). No errors or anything. Just doesn't show up on the screen.

It's just a simple ProgressBar

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I looked around and found nothing on this. Anyone have a solution please? Very frustrated.

Comment: do you try to set progress like this android:progress="10" ?

Comment: Nah I dont. I just add this to the XML and it runs in the UI. I dont tamper the code. It worked before the update :/

Comment: I don't know what project you write but maybe you should change minsdk version too (if you are using something new in your code)

Comment: @GigantoMK I had to change the minSdk to 15 cos the facebook login api wanted me to. What version should I change it to?

Comment: for example change it to 23, then test your app, if it works then you  should find some API functions which you are using that can run on high versions only

Comment: Nah man no luck :( @GigantoMK Should I turn to some support library for custom progress bars?

Comment: You can use Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar 
it will help you http://www.materialdoc.com/linear-progress/

Comment: Changing the min SDK won't do anything, that only specifies the minimum version needed to run the app. You don't need to use AppCompat for custom anything. Can you perhaps try changing the `layout_width` to something other than `wrap_content` say `100dp` perhaps your parent layout is causing an issue

Comment: @Pztar problem appears when project has been updated (sdk) so how can you explain what is the problem when it was running before?

Comment: @GigantoMK why are you telling him to change his minSDK to 23? That would limit his app to only M devices, that isn't the cause of his problem. Especially not for something as basic as a `ProgressBar`

Comment: @GigantoMK I just tried that and the bar is visible but the progress is NOT shown with the animation. indeterminate is also set to true. This is a weird bug

Comment: @Pztar I don't offer to change it at all. only for testing and understanding what the update changed